# Nested function and else condition not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, css

I am practicing JS doing a project and have run into issues (again).
Just upfront, to explain what i want.
I have the top level buttons with nation names, on click a pic will fade into a container just for that. It gets the pic from the first array on line 1.This all works very well. However...
When that container is visible, I want a click handler on the "next" button to the right. This handler is one function (line 29-42) which animates the second div(.containsNext) by changing opacity and rotate values.
This function also calls another function (next, this should change the target div background with pics from the new Array) and has an if else statement.
The if condition works as it is supposed to.
The else condition does not run, even if i take out the nested `next()` function.

I think the error (console doesn't return one) on the next function is the lines 15 and 16, I know those lines look "funny":-)

And the if statement in the wrapper function does not work either.

How to fix this? Please make sure to select France, Italy or Croatia buttons, or the next button will not respond at all (do not know why either).
One more question on the side, what would be an economical way to store the pics for all the nations arrays selected/triggered by the next button?
Also how to do implement the proper nations array to be selected based on the top button nation selection?

Thank you guys

```
function
   var imgLenght = 3;
   var currentImg = 1;
   function next() {
      var imgContainer = document.querySelector(".containsNext");
   if(currentImg > 0)
       {
       imgContainer.style.background = "url(" + "im[currentImg-1]" + ")";
       currentImg = currentImg - 1;
       }
   }
```

Link to the pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gPggLB

Comment: Look at the colors in your question, you have mismatched quotes.

Comment: ouch, thanks for that, guys
But the else statement in the wrapper function does still not work.

Comment: There's no `else` nor a nested function in the example?

Comment: @Teemu
The next() function is the nested one.
The else condition is in the function from line 29 to 42.
Line 39 else{} etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use correctly nested quotes:

```
  imgContainer.style.background = 'url("' + im[currentImg-1] + '")';
```

Comment: Thank you for that but the next function does not run, and still no error thrown. But it does not go to the second pic in the array.
Animation is ok, but nothing happens upon clicking the "next" button again

Comment: Ok i have figured it out now.
It is bit embarassing to say, but obviously the concatenation when setting the new background was wrong, then accidentally used "=" instead of "=="  in the if statement and the nested function had to be an argument in the callback.
Now I still need to figure out, how to implement the following, each nation has 3 pics in the im array. Should i do one array for every nation, or a large one for all nation and then extract them by index position?
And how do I make sure it recognizes which nation button has been clicked, and then chose the relevent pic from the im[]?

Comment: Actually, it does not work again. The back ground of the pics changes very randomly on click. For both the next and previous() functions.

Comment: @damianocelent if you have a new problem with code that is not included in the question, please open a new question with relevant code.

Comment: @Aprilion
I have now fixed all this, it finally works, but now the next question arises and I have no idea how to even try to implement that, is it ok to just ask?

Comment: it is best to say what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried and what exactly is the problem, including error messages from the console... but if you don't know how to even begin, you can still ask if you include what google search you tried before asking - although it might be better to follow programming tutorials before starting to program IMHO

Comment: @Aprilion
I have now already posted the new one, I would know a way how to do it, but its far from the ideal way.